# ِDo we have to make wudu separately after ghusl?

Tags: fiqh, wudu, taharah, ghusl

Salam,

Please clear this doubt with reference:

If we perform ghusl properly, is it necessary to do wudu after it or just the wudu during the ghusl is enough?
In ghusl we do a small wudu and I am told that it is enough, thus after ghusl we don't need to do separate wudu.

Answer (score 1):

Some References are in Turkish because I don't know how to translate. 
**"Prophet Mohammed (peace be upon him) would take Ghusl and would offer the Fajr sunnah (two rak'ahs sunnah and two rak'ahs fard). I don't remember him did take wudu after taking ghusl."**  (Ebû Dâvûd, Tahâret 98 (245); Nesâî, Tahâret 159; İbn Mâce, Tahâret 96; Müsned, VI, 68, 192, 253, 258).

From this hadith, which is considered to be referenced from a very trusted source, we can understand that it is not necessary to take wudu after proper Ghusl because he was offering salah after taking Ghusl.

There is also another hadith which is **not trusted** by Majmau'z-Zevaid. ***"One who takes wudu after taking Ghusl does not belong to us"***. The meaning of it is actually -while- you are taking the Ghusl you should take firstly wudu (which is normally taken before salah), and after take Ghusl. But this is not trusted and it was taken from "Taberânî, Mu'jem-ledger, XI, 213; Mu'cemü's-sagir". **Again this hadith is not considered to be trustworthy.**

I myself offer salah after taking Ghusl without taking wudu again.

Answer (score 1):

The one who has performed an obligatory Ghusl(except the Ghusl for medium [Istihazah](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2169/))  should not perform Wodhu for the [six things for which Wodhu is obligatory](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2158/), as long as none of [the seven things invalidating Wodhu](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2159/) has taken place during performing Ghusl or after getting it done.

After performing a Mustahab (recommended) Ghusl listed [here](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2192/) one can do all the acts for which Wudhu is obligatory. However, in this case, it is better to perform Wodhu as a recommended precaution. (Al-Ihtiyat Al-Mustahabb)

Recommended Ghusls which are performed with the intention of "Raja" (which means to perform an act of worship hoping it to be what Allah has really recommended) are not sufficient for performing the acts for which Wodhu is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If the person who is purifying himself limits it to ghusl and does not do wudoo’, that is sufficient. That applies to obligatory ghusl; as for other types of ghusl, it is not sufficient with no need for wudoo’, and he must do wudoo’ if he wants to pray. End quote.

It says in Haashiyat al-Saawi ‘ala al-Sharh al-Sagheer (1/173-174):